# Verbose and error log is not showing in Eclipse for Google Pixel device Android

Tags: android, eclipse

Please some one help me to get out of the issue,
I have google Pixel device and I was used this device for App developing but from the beginning I am unable to see the Verbose and any of the logs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: God can help you only in migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio :)

Comment: you could restart logging and retry (from restart log icon)  it sometimes hanging